# iOS Today Widget - Can app determine if it is enabled/disabled?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, widget

Can the application determine if the associated widget in the today center is enabled or disabled. I want to display a settings that is active when the widget is enabled and grayed out when the widget is disabled. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you found anything?